# Pass Map value to Spring MVC controller using <form:hidden>

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

On submitting the page, i need to do some process and send some data to the controller. I felt the 'Map' suits for my requirement to pass in the data. Here is what i am doing:

### JSP:

```
<form:hidden id="passMapData" path="passMapData"/>
```

### Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newPage/testData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String newPageTestData(@Valid @ModelAttribute("npf") NewPageForm npf, BindingResult result, Model model) {

}
```

### NewPageForm.java:

```
public class NewPageForm {
  private Map<String, String> passMapData = null;

  public Map<String, String> getPassMapData() {
    return passMapData;
  }

  public void setPassMapData(Map<String, String> passMapData) {
    this.passMapData = passMapData;
  }
}
```

### Issue:

On submitting the form, the BindingResult in the controller is showing error "IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Map]"

Cant we pass a Map type to controller in form submit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a Map<String,String> to a springMVC controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280395/passing-a-mapstring-string-to-a-springmvc-controller)

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<form:hidden id="passMapData" path="passMapData"/>` is used to pass the hidden `String` data. Basically it is a *hidden field* like `<input type='hidden'/>` in html.

You cannot pass the `HashMap` here,So your **NewPageForm.java** must be ,

```
public class NewPageForm {
  private String passMapData = null;

  public String getPassMapData() {
    return passMapData;
  }

  public void setPassMapData( String passMapData) {
    this.passMapData = passMapData;
  }
}
```

**Note :** If you need to pass the `HashMap` to the `controller` , just set the `Hashmap` in to the `request` of the `JSP` ,

```
request.setAttribute("passMapData",Your HashMap);
```

You can able to get the same `Hashmap` in the `controller` as ,

```
request.getAttribute("passMapData");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that we cannot pass Map in form submit. I really appreciated. I am gonna make it as string.