# How to pass Hasmap from Html to Spring controller in java

Tags: java, html, spring, hashmap

How to pass Hasmap from Html to Spring controller in java.And also I would like to know how to get it from the controller.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Post your code/ configuration for people to help you

Comment: @Soorapadman I just tried to pass it as a normal variable and I could see the map values in the url.  but in the controller i couldnt get it.

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-hashmap-form-example/ try this :) :)

Comment: and this too ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280395/passing-a-mapstring-string-to-a-springmvc-controller

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is nothing like passing hashmap from html to Spring controller. What you want to accomplish is actually making a http request to web application.

Create a form model which has `Map<String,String>` as class variable with appropriate setter and getter.

Then in your action;

```
  public @ResponseBody String formPost(@ModelAttribute YourFormClass form, HttpServletRequest request) {
      //Rest of your business logic
  }
```

Comment: Thanks.let me try to follow your method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help you.

HTML:

```
<html><body>
<input type="hidden" name="Hashmap" id="mymap">
</body>
<script>
var Map = new Map(); //push some values into this
var obj = Object.fromEntries(keyvalue);
        var StringKeyvalue = JSON.stringify(obj);
        console.log("entra babu nak idhi: ",StringKeyvalue)
        document.getElementById("mymap").value = StringKeyvalue;
</script>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
public String passingHashmap(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("Hashmap") 
String mapValues) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        Map<String, String> myHashMap = mapper.readValue(mapValues, new 
TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>(){});
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return true;
}
```