# @PathVariable Map syntax for url?

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller, request-mapping

I have a controller which looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/start/{params}", method = GET, produces = { APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
String doStart(@PathVariable("params") Map<String,String> startParams)
```

How do i send the `startParams` from the url?

All my tries ends up with:

> IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String]
>   to required type [java.util.Map]: no matching editors or conversion
>   strategy found

Also it is not possible to send empty like

`theurl/start/`

it gives

> dec 18, 2015 10:56:07 FM
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>   WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Is it somehow possible to send no params, or do i need a separate method for that?:

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280395/passing-a-mapstring-string-to-a-springmvc-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `@MatrixVariable` instead of `@PathVariable`.

have a look at this example [Spring Matrix variable usage](https://dzone.com/articles/just-what-are-spring-32-matrix-0)